# Visualizing clustering based on similarity score

Tags: python, graph, cluster-analysis, networkx, gephi

I have the following cross-tabulated data:

```
            biz   user1  user2  user3  user4
    user
    A         1      1      0      0
    B         1      1      0      0
    C         1      1      1      0
    D         1      0      0      0
    E         0      0      1      1
    F         0      0      1      1
    G         0      0      1      1
    J         0      0      0      1
    M         0      1      0      0
```

and using covariance turn it into:

```
   [ 1.  ,  0.75,  0.25,  0.  ],
   [ 0.75,  1.  ,  0.25,  0.  ],
   [ 0.25,  0.25,  1.  ,  0.75],
   [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.75,  1.  ]
```

Using the following code, I attempt to graph these data:

```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   import networkx as nx

    users=[]
    user_s=[(x+',')*4 for x in ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4']]
    for s in user_s:
        users.extend([e for e in s.split(',') if e!=''])

    X=[]
    user_s=[(x+',')*4 for x in ['32.5', '32.2', '30.4', '31.5']]
    for s in user_s:
        X.extend([float(e) for e in s.split(',') if e!=''])

    Y=[]
    user_s=[(x+',')*4 for x in ['-110', '-110', '-115', '-114']]
    for s in user_s:
        Y.extend([float(e) for e in s.split(',') if e!=''])    

    dat=pd.DataFrame({'user':users, 
        'biz':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'M', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'J'],
        'X':X, 'Y':Y})

    rel=pd.crosstab(dat.user, dat.biz, rownames=['biz'], colnames=['user']).transpose()
    cov=np.dot(rel.transpose(), rel)/np.diag(np.dot(rel.transpose(), rel))
    dat.groupby('user').mean()[['X', 'Y']]
    dat.groupby('user').mean()[['X', 'Y']]
    G=nx.Graph()
    for i in rel.columns.tolist():
        G.add_node(i, X=dat.loc[dat.user==i, 'X'].mean(), Y=dat.loc[dat.user==i, 'Y'].mean())


    for i in np.arange(0, cov.shape[0]):
        idx=np.where(cov[i,]>.0)[0].tolist() ##for column i, get index of cov values above quantile p
        for j in idx:
            if i!=j: #eliminates (0,0) as an edge bc its redundant
                G.add_edge(rel.columns[i],
                rel.columns[j],weight=cov[i,j],length=1/cov[i,j], width=cov[i,j])

    centrality=nx.degree_centrality(G)    
    pos=nx.spring_layout(G)
    nx.draw(G,pos, node_size=[centrality[key]*500 for key in centrality.keys()],
        cm=plt.cm.Spectral,edge_cm=plt.cm.Blues,
        width=[(x[2]['width']*2)**2 for x in G.edges(data=True)], alpha=.5)  
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,fontsize=16)
```

[graph produced by above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFA35.png)

Note how user1 and user2 are highly correlated, as are user3 and user4; while the relationship between the two clusters is weak.

I want to do two things:

- Have the two groups have the same color(to tell membership of cluster)
- Have the distance between user1 & user2 be smaller than between user1 and user3. Similarly for user3 and user4.

I am new to graphing so if you can suggest an algorithm that would aid in the clustering, I would be super grateful.

My main goal is to visualize this on a much larger dataset (10k users)

Answer (score 0):

In the question's graph, connections are determined by non-zero weights between the users; therefore, to check for highly 
similar groups, I defined weights needed to count as a connection as those with correlation above .75. This creates islands
and can be plotted as different groups using the function below:

```
    G=nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from(['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'u4', 'u5', 'u6', 'u7', 'u8'])
    G.add_edges_from([
    ('u1', 'u2', {'weight':.75}),  ('u1','u5', {'weight':1}),('u2', 'u5', {'weight':.75}),
    ('u3', 'u6', {'weight':.8}), ('u4', 'u6', {'weight':.65}),('u3', 'u4', {'weight':.75}),
    #('u3', 'u7', {'weight':.5}),
    #('u2', 'u4', {'weight':.3}),
    ('u7', 'u8', {'weight':.9})])

    def draw_group_graph(graph, edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues,node_cmap=plt.cm.jet, w_pwr=3):
        plt.figure()
        pos=nx.spring_layout(graph)

        nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph,pos,
        width=[nx.get_edge_attributes(graph,'weight')[i]*w_pwr for i in  G.edges()],
        edge_cmap=edge_cmap, 
        edge_color=[nx.get_edge_attributes(graph,'weight')[i] for i in  G.edges()])

        nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, labels=[str(i) for i in weights])

        g_list=[j for j in nx.connected_component_subgraphs(graph) if len(j.edges())>0]

        col_val=np.linspace(0,1,num=len(g_list)).tolist()
        i=0; print(len(g_list))
        for g in g_list:
            print(i, "color:",node_cmap(col_val[i]) )
            nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos, node_color=node_cmap(col_val[i]), alpha=.6,
            node_size=[nx.degree_centrality(g)[i]*1000 for i in  g.nodes()])
            nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos, fontsize=16)
            i=i+1
```

[Above defined graph plotted using different groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eROVi.png)

Comment: where are you getting "weights" from?

Comment: @ethanenglish The weights are coming from a normalized covariance matrix; the above is a weighted graph.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider a [dendrogram](http://docs.roguewave.com/imsl/net/5.0.1/chartpg/images/SampleDendrogram001.png).

You can use [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html) to generate one.